# How can we list all the parameters in the aws parameter store using Boto3? There is no ssm.list_parameters in boto3 documentation?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

[SSM — Boto 3 Docs 1.9.64 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html)

`get_parameters` doesn't list all parameters?

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.describe_parameters

Answer (score 14):

For those who wants to just copy-paste the code:

```py
import boto3
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
parameters = ssm.describe_parameters()['Parameters']
```

Beware of the limit of max 50 parameters!

Answer (score 9):

This code will get all parameters, by recursively fetching until there are no more (50 max is returned per call):

```
import boto3
def get_resources_from(ssm_details):
  results = ssm_details['Parameters']
  resources = [result for result in results]
  next_token = ssm_details.get('NextToken', None)
  return resources, next_token
    
def main()
  config = boto3.client('ssm', region_name='us-east-1')
  next_token = ' '
  resources = []
  while next_token is not None:
    ssm_details = config.describe_parameters(MaxResults=50, NextToken=next_token)
    current_batch, next_token = get_resources_from(ssm_details)
    resources += current_batch
  print(resources)
  print('done')
```

Comment: please consider making an explanation of the solution that you've provided.

Comment: I've updated, let me know if you have any other suggestions

Answer (score 3):

You can use get_paginator api. find below example, In my use case i had to get all the values of SSM parameter store and wanted to compare it with a string.

```
import boto3
import sys

LBURL = sys.argv[1].strip()
client = boto3.client('ssm')
p = client.get_paginator('describe_parameters')
paginator = p.paginate().build_full_result()
for page in paginator['Parameters']:
    response = client.get_parameter(Name=page['Name'])
    value = response['Parameter']['Value']
    if LBURL in value:
        print("Name is: " + page['Name'] + " and Value is: " + value)
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the responses from above/below(?) (by [Val Lapidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12889782/val-lapidus)) inspired me to expand it to this (as his solution doesn't get the SSM parameter value, and some other, additional details).

The downside here is that the AWS function `client.get_parameters()` only allows 10 names per call.

There's one referenced function call in this code (`to_pdatetime(...)`) that I have omitted - it just takes the `datetime` value and makes sure it is a "naive" datetime. This is because I am ultimately dumping this data to an Excel file using `pandas`, which doesn't deal well with timezones.

```py
from typing import List, Tuple
from boto3 import session
from mypy_boto3_ssm import SSMClient

def ssm_params(aws_session: session.Session = None) -> List[dict]:
    """
    Return a detailed list of all the SSM parameters.
    """
    
    # -------------------------------------------------------------
    #
    #
    # -------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_parameter_values(ssm_client: SSMClient,  ssm_details: dict) -> Tuple[list, str]:
        """
        Retrieve additional attributes for the SSM parameters contained in the 'ssm_details'
        dictionary passed in.
        """
        # Get the details
        ssm_param_details = ssm_details['Parameters']

        # Just the names, ma'am
        param_names = [result['Name'] for result in ssm_param_details]

        # Get the parames, including the values
        ssm_params_with_values = ssm_client.get_parameters(Names=param_names,
                                                           WithDecryption=True)
        resources = []

        result: dict
        for result in ssm_params_with_values['Parameters']:

            # Get the matching parameter from the `ssm_details` dict since this has some of the fields
            # that aren't in the `ssm_params_with_values` returned from "get_arameters".
            param_details = next((zz for zz in ssm_param_details if zz.get('Name', None) == result['Name']), {})

            param_policy = param_details.get('Policies', None)
            if len(param_policy) == 0:
                param_policy = None

            resources.append({
                    'Name': result['Name'],
                    'LastModifiedDate': to_pdatetime(result['LastModifiedDate']),
                    'LastModifiedUser': param_details.get('LastModifiedUser', None),
                    'Version': result['Version'],
                    'Tier': param_details.get('Tier', None),
                    'Policies': param_policy,
                    'ARN': result['ARN'],
                    'DataType': result.get('DataType', None),
                    'Type': result.get('Type', None),
                    'Value': result.get('Value', None)
                    })

        next_token = ssm_details.get('NextToken', None)
        return resources, next_token

    # -------------------------------------------------------------
    #
    #
    # -------------------------------------------------------------
    if aws_session is None:
        raise ValueError('No session.')

    # Create SSM client
    aws_ssm_client = aws_session.client('ssm')

    next_token = ' '
    ssm_resources = []

    while next_token is not None:
        # The "describe_parameters" call gets a whole lot of info on the defined SSM params,
        # except their actual values. Due to this limitation let's call the nested function
        # to get the values, and a few other details. 
        ssm_descriptions = aws_ssm_client.describe_parameters(MaxResults=10,
                                                              NextToken=next_token)

        # This will get additional details for the params, including values.
        current_batch, next_token = get_parameter_values(ssm_client=aws_ssm_client,
                                                         ssm_details=ssm_descriptions)
        ssm_resources += current_batch

    print(f'SSM Parameters: {len(ssm_resources)}')
    return ssm_resources
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python)[aws](/questions/tagged/aws)[boto3](/questions/tagged/boto3)[amazon-web-services](/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services)

Answer (score 0):

There's no ListParameters only DescribeParameter, which lists all the paremeters, or you can set filters.

Boto3 Docs Link:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.describe_parameters

AWS API Documentation Link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeParameters.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_parameters()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_parameters) and [`get_parameters_by_path()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Client.get_parameters_by_path).

Comment: get_parameters() lists only one parameter and get_parameters_by_path() have a limitation of only 10 parameters.

Comment: How about `describe_parameters()`?

Comment: describe_parameters() can list max of 50 parameters

Comment: You can paginate `describe_parameters()`. "You can specify the NextToken in a subsequent call to get the next set of results."

Answer (score 0):

Use `paginators`.

```
paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_parameters')
```

More information [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ssm.html#SSM.Paginator.DescribeParameters).